# Jquery doesn't run despite being added to react-app

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have a filename as dashboard.js written in jquery. I installed jquery and add it to main_panel.js

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import Dashboard from '../assets/js/demo_1/dashboard.js'
```

When run react-app, it shows as below:

```
src\assets\js\demo_1\dashboard.js
  Line 57:24:   'successColor' is not defined        no-undef
  Line 126:28:  'Chart' is not defined               no-undef
  Line 226:28:  'Chart' is not defined               no-undef
  Line 412:27:  'Chart' is not defined               no-undef
  Line 502:30:  'Chart' is not defined               no-undef
  Line 525:32:  'Chart' is not defined               no-undef
  Line 623:33:  'Marketing_data_3_1' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 624:33:  'Marketing_data_3_2' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 625:33:  'Marketing_data_3_2' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 626:33:  'Marketing_data_3_2' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 632:31:  'Chart' is not defined               no-undef
  Line 903:27:  'Chart' is not defined               no-undef
  Line 924:27:  'Chart' is not defined               no-undef
  Line 945:27:  'Chart' is not defined               no-undef
  Line 966:27:  'Chart' is not defined               no-undef
  Line 983:20:  'JustGage' is not defined            no-undef
  Line 1004:4:  'jQuery' is not defined              no-undef
```

Hope everyone help me fix this

Comment: can you try using `import $ from 'jquery'`? This might fix the issue.

Comment: I tried but it not work

Comment: But did you import it inside `dashboard.js`?

Comment: I tried importing it inside but it did not run. Sometimes I create react app by npx, it run but sometimes not